# GetObject operation: Access Denied when trying to read a file in an S3 bucket using boto

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a file in called 'myfile.txt' located in my S3 bucket and I'm using the following code to try and open the contents of that file as follows:

```
bucketname = 'my-bucket'  
file_to_read = '/files/myfile.txt'

fileobj = s3.get_object(
    Bucket=bucketname, 
    Key=file_to_read)
    

filedata = fileobj['Body'].read()

filecontents = filedata.decode('utf-8') 

print(filecontents)
```

When I try to run this file, my Cloudwatch logs show the following error:

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied
```

**What I have tried:**

I have checked the policy of the applicable role name that is associated with my Lambda fucntion to ensure that there are sufficient permissions to use the `get_object` method within the my s3 bucket, which I believe is what the below screenshot shows.

[image]

[image]

Yet still I receive the `Access Denied` error.
I'm now looking for suggestions as to what else I should check or rectify to alleviate this issue.

Comment: Can I suggest you try changing actions to do wildcard mapping on S3. That is: "s3:*" ? If that doesn't work, try removing "sid"

Comment: @Greg Do you mean change to “Resource”: “s3:*” ?

Comment: I mean change the action. The way I set it up is "Statement":[{"Effect": "Allow","Action": ["s3:*"],"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*/*"}]

Comment: @Greg Ok thank you. I will try this and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here lies not in the fact that the S3 bucket permissions were incorrect (though of course you should check this too) but in the fact that the directory path contained an erroneous leading '/'.

It should be:

```
file_to_read = 'files/myfile.txt'
```

It is important to note that, sometimes, when a file is physically not present or the path to it is incorrect, AWS will return a permission denied error.

This was what occurred in my case.